# Hyperledger Fabcar: Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

Im trying to run the latest Fabric 1.4 Fabcar on my local machine. Iv installed the prerequisites cleaned down docker images and run the following commands

```
fabric-samples/fabcar: ./startFabric.sh java
```

I can see the chaincode being installed on the peers but once it reaches the channel I get the following error

`Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 254'

Iv also tried

```
./startFabric.sh javascript and ./startFabric.sh
```

But I get the same result. I was able to run and query '''first-network''' ok, but cannot get Fabcar started :(

Also If I do an mvn test from the java app I get

```
Caused by: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: 
org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock 
for channel mychannel failed with peer peer0.org1.example.com.  Status 
FAILURE, details: Channel Channel{id: 1, name: mychannel} Sending 
proposal with transaction: 
e545101510caaf0cbb9ff5e193b648308a93e53a459599c2d85f2cd9d4f181bc to 
Peer{ id: 2, name: peer0.org1.example.com, channelName: mychannel, url: 
grpcs://localhost:7051, mspid: Org1MSP} failed because of: gRPC 
failure=Status{code=UNKNOWN, description=access denied: channel 
[mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP], cause=null}
```

Any help appreciated

Startup logs

````
Installing smart contract on peer1.org2.example.com
+ docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:10051 -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp -e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt cli peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 1.0 -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/fabcar/java -l java
2019-10-21 19:59:41.619 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-10-21 19:59:41.619 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
2019-10-21 19:59:42.006 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> INFO 003 Installed remotely response:<status:200 payload:"OK" >
+ echo 'Instantiating smart contract on mychannel'
Instantiating smart contract on mychannel
+ docker exec -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -l java -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P 'AND('\''Org1MSP.member'\'','\''Org2MSP.member'\'')' --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
2019-10-21 19:59:42.387 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-10-21 19:59:42.388 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1```

docker ps -a

```CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
44d6dd0274cb        hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"              6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                                                     cli
ff7b5068437e        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp                       peer0.org1.example.com
5806c85ba8b7        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp                       peer0.org2.example.com
fd722bc9df2d        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:10051->10051/tcp                     peer1.org2.example.com
9031600fe52a        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8051->8051/tcp                       peer1.org1.example.com
69c4f20893e8        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"                6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                       orderer.example.com
8325f89e702a        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb          "tini -- /docker-ent…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp   couchdb0
7d83b2cff3c3        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb          "tini -- /docker-ent…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8984->5984/tcp   couchdb3
0a94844d9fe4        hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                       ca_peerOrg1
1da63403427f        hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        7054/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8054->8054/tcp             ca_peerOrg2
9e3ece2b615a        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb          "tini -- /docker-ent…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7984->5984/tcp   couchdb2
91e08de9c145        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb          "tini -- /docker-ent…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6984->5984/tcp   couchdb1```
````

Answer (score 4):

there might be lots of reason for the failure either there would be incorrect path setup or chaincode installed peer might not be accessible.

can you try out by using these commands and try to spin up again

docker kill $(docker ps -q) 
docker rm $(docker ps -aq) 
docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)

Comment: Same result :(. Im gonna remove Hyperledger from my system and start from the prerequisite again. Ill let you know how it goes. Big thanks Rahul for the response

Comment: Success!!! After I execute your command, I removed hyper ledger from my machine and reinstalled the binaries. Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200 :)

Comment: Spook too soon. I get a 200 when do a ./startFabric.sh javascript. But when I do a ./startFabric.sh java I get ```Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 254```

Comment: After install java dependencies, doing a mvn test from the java package I get ```
org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.GatewayRuntimeException: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ServiceDiscoveryException: Could not meet endorsement policy for chaincode fabcar```

Comment: ```java.net.UnknownHostException: peer0.org2.example.com```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to get past the `java.net.UnknownHostException` issue which was the root problem to the question was to change the system host file in /etc/hosts by adding the following...

```
127.0.0.1 orderer.example.com

127.0.0.1 peer1.org1.example.com
127.0.0.1 peer0.org2.example.com
127.0.0.1 peer0.org1.example.com
127.0.0.1 peer1.org2.example.com

127.0.0.1 ca_peerOrg1
127.0.0.1 ca_peerOrg2
127.0.0.1 couchdb1 
127.0.0.1 couchdb2
127.0.0.1 couchdb3
127.0.0.1 couchbd0
```

mvn test worked then :) Hope this helps others